# How to add more info in the results from a query on cosmos db using a dictionary?

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb

I have some data stored in Comsos db and some other in SQL. The data from SQL is retrieved every 5 minutes and is stored in a ConcurrentDictionary. I need to query the data on Cosmos and add more info to the results using the dictionary. So here is the code:

```
public IAsyncEnumerable<LogDto> GetLogsAsync(string tenantId, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return _container.GetItemLinqQueryable<Log>()
                .Where(l => l.TenantId != null && l.TenantId.ToLower() == tenantId.ToLower()) 
                .Take(10)
                .Select(l => new LogDto()
                {
                    SerialId = l.SerialId,
                    SiteId = l.SiteId,
                    SiteName = _cacheService._siteDictionary[l.SiteId],
                })
                .ToFeedIterator()
                .ToAsyncEnumerable(cancellationToken);
        }
```

But I get the following error:

The specified query includes 'member indexer' which is currently not supported.

Is there any workaround for this? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to run the query first, then iterate over the resulting collection and set the `SiteName` property once each item is in-memory since you can't do this as part of the Cosmos query.

Try something like this:

```cs
public async IAsyncEnumerable<LogDto> GetLogsAsync(string tenantId, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
   var results = _container.GetItemLinqQueryable<Log>()
                .Where(l => l.TenantId != null && l.TenantId.ToLower() == tenantId.ToLower()) 
                .Take(10)
                .Select(l => new LogDto()
                {
                    SerialId = l.SerialId,
                    SiteId = l.SiteId
                })
                .ToFeedIterator()
                .ToAsyncEnumerable(cancellationToken);

   await foreach (var result in results)
   {
      result.SiteName = _cacheService._siteDictionary[result.SiteId];
      yield return result;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! how much overhead do you think it may cause if we try it in scenarios with large data? I mean how much slower it would become and does it make it to store all the data in buffer before sending the results or because of using yield it wont?

Comment: It's hard to say definitively without knowing more about your application, the best advice I can offer is to try it out and measure your performance. I don't think this method alone will necessarily try to store all data in memory, but other code that uses this method might.